# How to read values from a text file, store it in array, and loop through it?

Tags: python, for-loop, if-statement, readfile

Based on package dimension: `Height`, `Length`, `Width`, and `Weight`, I'm creating 3 package categories: `Letter`, `Parcel-Small`, and `Parcel-Large`. Here is the code in python:

```
def category(row):
    if(row['Height'] <=0.98 and row['Length'] <= 9.84
       and row['Width'] <= 13.89 and row['WEIGHT'] <= 1.65):
        val = 'Letter'
    elif(row['Height'] <=6.29 and row['Length'] <= 13.77
         and row['Width'] <= 17.71 and row['WEIGHT'] <= 4.4):
        val = 'Parcel-Small'
    elif(row['Height'] <=6.29 and row['Length'] <= 13.77
         and row['Width'] <= 17.71 and row['WEIGHT'] <= 4.4):
        val = 'Parcel-Large'
    return val
```

As seen these dimension values are hardcoded. I want to take the inputs (`Package Category`, `Height`, `Length`, `Width`, and `Weight`) from a text file which in the format like this :

```
Package Category : Height, Length, Width, Weight
Small:2,3,4,10
Medium:3,5,7,15
Large:5,7,9,20
```

It should read as many categories as specified by user and the code should be something like this:

```
for each package category:
    if(row['Height'] <= Height and row['Length'] <=Length
       and row['Width'] <= Width and row['WEIGHT'] <= Weight):
        val = 'Package Category'
```

Can someone give a actual code for the pseudo code given above?

Comment: Be more specific on you file format.

Comment: I can help you with this, but as written you're going to run into some issues.
If a package meets more than one criteria it will always go in the first if statement it matches, if it doesn't meet any category criteria it won't be assigned a type at all. I assume your for loop is meant to go through a list of packages and assign them a category?

Comment: @whieronymus yes, that's not the matter of concern, I just want to get rid of hard coded values and pick the package category names and dimension from a text file. it will always meet the requirements.

Comment: check my answer, I still need to know what kind of file you're parsing in order to get you the complete answer, but that function will categorize your list of packages based on an input of package types. (Assuming they're ordered smallest to largest)

Answer (score 0):

With a small loop you can parse that file into a `list` of `dicts` like...

#### Code:

```
package_types = []
with open('file1', 'rU') as f:
    header = next(f)
    columns = [x.strip() for x in header.split(':')[1].split(',')]
    for line in f:
        name, data = line.split(':')
        package_types.append(dict(zip(columns,
            [float(x) for x in data.split(',')])))
        package_types[-1]['type'] = name

for package_type in package_types:
    print(package_type)

    # if package_type['Height'] <= Height and not ...
```

#### Results:

```
{'Width': 4.0, 'Length': 3.0, 'type': 'Small', 'Weight': 10.0, 'Height': 2.0}
{'Width': 7.0, 'Length': 5.0, 'type': 'Medium', 'Weight': 15.0, 'Height': 3.0}
{'Width': 9.0, 'Length': 7.0, 'type': 'Large', 'Weight': 20.0, 'Height': 5.0}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's my solution:

## Example of a configuration file (*categories.txt*):

```
Letter : 0.98, 9.84, 13.89, 1.65
Parcel-Small : 3.63, 11.80, 15.80, 3.02
Parcel-Large : 6.29, 13.77, 17.71, 4.4
```

## Function to parse the file:

```
def parse_file(f):
    categories = [] # Create empty list
    for line in f:
        line = line.strip() # Remove leading and trailing spaces
        name, tail = line.split(':') # Separate the name of the category from its specifications
        height, length, width, weight = tail.split(',') # Separate each specification
        # Convert each specification to a number (float) and put them all in a dictionary
        specs = {'height': float(height),
                 'length': float(length),
                 'width': float(width),
                 'weight': float(weight)}
        categories.append((name, specs)) # Append the name and the specifications to a list
    return categories
```

## Opening the file and building the list:

```
with open('categories.txt', 'r') as f:
    categories = parse_file(f)
```

## Function to classify the measurements into a category:

```
def category(height, length, width, weight):
    for name, specs in categories:
        if height <= specs['height'] and length <= specs['length'] and width <= specs['width'] and weight <= specs['weight']:
            return name
```

## Usage example:

```
print category(3, 11, 15, 3)
```

## Output:

```
Parcel-Small
```

Comment: You should note that if your input in function `category()` doesn't meet any criteria, by default it is going to return `None`.

Answer (score 0):

The format you have chosen for the package categories definitions file is somewhat awkward to parse—it's *almost* a csv format file, but not quite (it uses multiple delimiters and the placement of whitespace in it is inconsistent). That said, here's something that deals with it and does the processing you say you want:

```
import csv
from collections import namedtuple

def as_csv(filename):
    """ Make configuration file look like it's in csv format. """
    with open(filename, newline='') as file:  # in Python 2 change newline='' to mode='rb'
        next(file)  # ignore first row
        for line in file:
            yield line.replace(':', ',')

PackageSpec = namedtuple('PackageSpec', 'category, height, length, width, weight')
DATA_TYPES = str, float, float, float, float

package_specs = [PackageSpec(*(datatype(val) for (datatype, val) in zip(DATA_TYPES, data)))
                    for data in csv.reader(as_csv('package_categories.txt'))]

def category(row):
    for spec in package_specs:
        if(row['Height'] <= spec.height and row['Length'] <= spec.length
           and row['Width'] <= spec.width and row['Weight'] <= spec.weight):
            return spec.category

sample_row = dict(Height=3, Length=5, Width=7, Weight=15)
print(category(sample_row))  # -> Medium
```

Answer (score -1):

Ok, I'm sure it's probably bad form to post an incomplete answer, but this is really the only way to find out what he's looking for.

We still need to know which file format you're using for your list of categories and your list of packages.

```
# This is the list of actual packages you're trying to categorize
# Codes not ready yet, we still need to open whatever kind of file
# You plan to use

list_of_real_packages = "CSV File?"

# This assumes categories are ordered smallest to largest
# We need to parse a real file, I'm just showing what it might look
# like based on your example
sample_categories_spreadsheet = [
    {
        'name': 'letter',
        'height': 0.98,
        'length': 9.84,
        'width': 13.89,
        'weight': 1.65
    },
    {
        'name': 'parcel-small',
        'height': 6.29,
        'length': 13.77,
        'width': 17.71,
        'weight': 4.4
    },
    {
        'name': 'parcel-large',
        'height': 12.00,
        'length': 20.00,
        'width': 25.00,
        'weight': 10
    },

]


def get_category_per_package_in_list(list_or_file_with_real_package_dimensions):
    package_number = 1
    package_list_with_categories = []

    # Check each package to see if it meets current categories criteria
    # Smallest to largest, because a small package will meet multiple criteria
    for package in list_or_file_with_real_package_dimensions:
        current_package = {}
        current_package['package_id'] = package_number,
        current_package['height'] = package['height'],
        current_package['length'] = package['length'],
        current_package['width'] = package['width'],
        current_package['weight'] = package['weight'],
        for catagory in sample_categories_spreadsheet:
            if package['height'] <= category['height']:
                if package['length'] <= category['length']:
                    if package['width'] <= category['width']:
                        if package['weight'] <= category['weight']:
                            current_package['category'] = category['name']

    # It's possible there is a very long skinny package that doesn't meet
    # any criteria, so we'll give it a category so we can look into it
    # after we sort the more standard packages
    else:
        current_package['category'] = 'Outside range of given categories'

    package_list_with_categories.append(new_package)
    return package_list_with_categories

list_of_packages = get_category_per_package_in_list()
```